# Run ant plugin in maven in eclipse when building project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant, maven-plugin

I need to run an ant build file every time sources change in the project in eclipse. Our current solution is using an ant builder but for some reason, the ant builder runs twice and if we swap places with the maven builder, the maven builder will return back to the same place.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by _"swap places"_? Switching the order of these project builders? When a file will be changed, all project builders will be triggered again. So make sure, not to have such cycles.

Comment: Yes, so the order of the builders change after the ant builder runs. How can I find such cycles?

Comment: The order of project builders is changed by directly or indirectly editing the `.project` file (this is not something that Eclipse changes by itself; but might be done by the Ant script used as project builder or by the `pom.xml` file). Changing the `.project` file might be cause a cycle since changing this files triggers a new build.